# how to read from textField by clicking on button?

Tags: java

I want to read file from my textField by clicking on check button.If I am clicking on check button it is showing nothing.it should show content in textFiled_2.but its not reading a file from textField .
Please help.Thanks in advance.

```
public class HLS {
    private JFrame frmHttpsLiveStreaming;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HLS window = new HLS();
                    window.frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public HLS() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming = new JFrame();
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setTitle("HTTPS Live Streaming");
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setBounds(100, 100, 494, 322);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Open File");
        btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser fs=new JFileChooser(new File("c:\\"));
                fs.setDialogTitle("Open a file");
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".m3u8",""));
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".ts",""));
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".m3u",""));
                fs.showOpenDialog(null);
                File file = fs.getSelectedFile();
                textField.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

                }
            });
        btnBrowse.setBounds(336, 7, 89, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Clear");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField_2.setText("");

            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(237, 39, 89, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Save Log File");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser fs=new JFileChooser(new File("c:\\"));
                fs.setDialogTitle("Save Log File");
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".txt","TEXT FILE"));
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".doc","DOCUMENT FILE"));
                int result=fs.showSaveDialog(null);
                if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                     String content=textField_2.getText();
                     File file=fs.getSelectedFile();
                     try{
                         FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file.getPath());
                         fw.write(content);
                         fw.flush();
                         fw.close();
                     }catch (Exception e2){
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e2.getMessage());
                 }      
            }
        }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(168, 239, 131, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setToolTipText("TOP");
        textField_2.setBounds(27, 73, 418, 155);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblUrl = new JLabel("URL");
        lblUrl.setBounds(83, 11, 24, 14);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(lblUrl);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(116, 11, 210, 19);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Check");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ***
```

### //HERE IS THE PROBLEM.

---

```
                 try{
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                     textField_2.read(br,null);
                     br.close();
                     textField_2.requestFocus();
                 }
                 catch(Exception e){


                 }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(126, 39, 89, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    }
}
```

please help.

Comment: Have you put some debug statements in? Do you get any error message?

Comment: no.I am not getting any error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add 'file' as a field to be accessed from other methods.
2. Reading from a text file is implemented as 'while' loop, you may want to change if its binary data.
3. You probably want to change JTextField to JTextArea if its text data.

This compiles and tested :

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HLS {

    private JFrame frmHttpsLiveStreaming;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField;
    // file is accessed to the whole class
    private File file;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HLS window = new HLS();
                    window.frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public HLS() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming = new JFrame();
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setTitle("HTTPS Live Streaming");
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setBounds(100, 100, 494, 322);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnBrowse = new JButton("Open File");
        btnBrowse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser fs = new JFileChooser(new File("c:\\"));
                fs.setDialogTitle("Open a file");
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".m3u8", ""));
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".ts", ""));
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".m3u", ""));
                fs.showOpenDialog(null);
                file = fs.getSelectedFile();
                textField.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());

            }
        });
        btnBrowse.setBounds(336, 7, 89, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Clear");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField_2.setText("");

            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(237, 39, 89, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("Save Log File");
        btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JFileChooser fs = new JFileChooser(new File("c:\\"));
                fs.setDialogTitle("Save Log File");
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".txt", "TEXT FILE"));
                fs.setFileFilter(new FileTypeFilter(".doc", "DOCUMENT FILE"));
                int result = fs.showSaveDialog(null);
                if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    String content = textField_2.getText();
                    File file = fs.getSelectedFile();
                    try {
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getPath());
                        fw.write(content);
                        fw.flush();
                        fw.close();
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e2.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(168, 239, 131, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setToolTipText("TOP");
        textField_2.setBounds(27, 73, 418, 155);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblUrl = new JLabel("URL");
        lblUrl.setBounds(83, 11, 24, 14);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(lblUrl);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(116, 11, 210, 19);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Check");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // HERE IS THE PROBLEM.

                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String line;
                    // System.out.println(file.toString());

                    // read text from file until the end. add the content 
                    // to the existing data.
                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                        // "\n" will be useful for JTextArea
                        textField_2.setText(textField_2.getText() + "\n" + line);
                        //System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    //textField_2.read(br, null);
                    br.close();
                    //textField_2.requestFocus();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(126, 39, 89, 23);
        frmHttpsLiveStreaming.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    }
}
```

Comment: For button2 u need to change : File file = fs.getSelectedFile(); to file = fs.getSelectedFile(); since its already defined as a field - but i didnt check button2 functionality.

Comment: I have a question.
what code should i required to open url from text field 1?
it should work like pasting URL in text field 1 and it should read the URL by clicking on check button and display it in textfield 2.
so what will be the code?